# Add additional payload/ID in Facebook button in Messenger Platform

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-webhooks

I am quite new to facebook chat bot.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons/

I can define button like this.

```
{
  "type": "postback",
  "title": "<BUTTON_TEXT>",
  "payload": "<STRING_SENT_TO_WEBHOOK>"
}
```

I have different payload (E.g For course, student). How can I put ID information inside that button as additional information?

Do I have to define like `course_1`, `course_2`, `student_5`, `student_8` in order to send type and ID?

Answer (score 0):

The payload can contain a string up to 1000 characters, what you pass as payload is up to you. Looking at your example you could use something like "course_1" or a combination like "course_1, student_8".